# How do I enable keyboard inputs in full screen mode?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, fullscreen

I heard that the flash action script 3 is disabled the keyboard interaction on full screen mode. How can I enable.

Answer (score 9):

Keyboard input except for a few keys (see below) is not available in fullscreen mode for security reasons.
**You can not enable these** (unless you are running in Air or a standalone player)

> Full-screen mode is initiated in response to a mouse click or key press by the user; the movie cannot change Stage.displayState without user input. Flash Player restricts keyboard input in full-screen mode. **Acceptable keys include keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode and non-printing keys such as arrows, space, Shift, and Tab keys**. Keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode are: Escape (Windows, Linux, and Mac), Control+W (Windows), Command+W (Mac), and Alt+F4.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState

Comment: so, is there any way to enable that?

Answer (score 5):

As of Flash 11.3, there is a way.

You have to go Fullscreen with this code:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

And add a param to the HTML:

```
<param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" />
```

Comment: We have observed graphical issues using fullscreen interactive mode on some 11.3 builds of flash player, such as displaying a blank black screen. Bumping the check up to 11.4 and otherwise falling back on regular fullscreen mode fixed this for us. Might be useful to someone else.